# Change width of every 3rd cell in collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to change the width of every 3rd cell in a collection view. Currently, I'm setting the width and height of elements like this:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    return CGSize(width: width / 2, height: width/2)
}
```

How can I select every 3rd element in the collection view and make that element full width? In css, it'd be element:nth-child(3n), so something similar to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a good use of the `modulus` operator! (Or, really, `%`)

```
let offset = 0 //modify to change where it starts
return (indexPath.row % 3 + offset) == 0 ? fullSize : normalSize
```

Comment: Was just about to answer with a modulus answer. But just to help out others that see this in the future he is returning a `CGSize` here and not a width so you may want to update your code.

Comment: Thanks @NSGangster I was just about to ask for a CGSize answer.

Comment: The code is meant to be subbed in with whatever you want to use - I don't know the parameters for "normal" vs full width, updated placeholders.